# How to jump when player is upside down in a spherical world, using FauxGravity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

### What I try to do

I'm trying to get jumping working all over the sphere and not just at the top while using FauxGravity.

### How it works currently

My character jumps correctly when he is on top but when he is in the bottom of the sphere the jump doesn't take place.

[image: Example]

#### FauxGravityAttractor

```
[SerializeField] private float gravity = -9.81f;

public void Attract(Rigidbody body) {
    Vector3 gravityUp = (body.position - transform.position).normalized;
    Vector3 localUp = body.transform.up;
    
    // Apply downwards gravity to body
    body.AddForce(gravityUp * gravity);
    // Align bodies up axis with the centre of planet
    body.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(localUp,gravityUp) * body.rotation;
}
```

#### FauxGravityBody

```
FauxGravityAttractor planet;
new Rigidbody rigidbody;

void Awake()
{
    planet = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Planet").GetComponent<FauxGravityAttractor>();
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    // Disable rigidbody gravity and rotation as this is simulated in GravityAttractor script
    rigidbody.useGravity = false;
    rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Allow this body to be influenced by planet's gravity
    planet.Attract(rigidbody);
}
```

#### Sample Jumping

```
void Jump()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isOnGround)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        isOnGround = false;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Planet"))
    {
        isOnGround = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you not find direction to the middle of the sphere and add force in the other direction?

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks for the response. I have tried to do this but dont seem to do it correctly at all... If you have example of this is would be very much appreciated. It's my second week using Unity so things are a bit complicated still.

Comment: @BugFinder After sometime I managed to solve this problem of mine. So thank you for trying to help<3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### FauxGravity jumping problem solved

All you need to do is `AddRelativeForce` to your `rigidbody`

Read more about [RelativeForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html)

```
    // JUMPING
    private void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && onGround)
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(0, forceConst, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
            onGround = false;
        }
    }
```